# SWIG: wrap enum to c#

Tags: c#, c++, enums, swig

I can't wrap c++ enum member to C# using SWIG. The size of c++ enum members is exceed Int32. In C# default type of enum memeber is Int32, thus I have compilation error. Although I follow the [instructions](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/CSharp.html#CSharp_enum_underlying_type), I can't solve the problem.

**MyClass.h**

```
class  MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {}
    ~MyClass() {}
    enum  BigNumbers
    {
        big = 0x80000000, bigger
    };
};
```

**MyClass.i**

```
%module cpp

%{
    #include "MyClass.h"
%}
%include "MyClass.h"

%typemap(csbase) BigNumbers "uint"
%inline %{
  enum BigNumbers { big=0x80000000, bigger };
%}
```

As result i get follow member in generated c# wrapper, which cause compilation error `cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'`

**MyClass.cs**

```
  public enum BigNumbers {
    big = 0x80000000,
    bigger
  }
```

and global uint enum in separate file:

**BigNumbers.cs**

```
public enum BigNumbers : uint {
  big = 0x80000000,
  bigger
}
```

While I want to get it in `MyClass.cs` as member of MyClass.

Please, anyone help me!

Comment: You can specify the underlying type for an `enum`

Comment: I'm just learning SWIG. Could you write a little more about.

Comment: I don't know anything about SWIG, but you can define an enum's type like this `public enum MyEnum : long { whatever = long.MaxValue }`

Comment: Yes! it is exactly what i want to get automatically from enum in  C++ code, but can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry for really dumb question, i should had to read the manual better.
Correct content of interface file is as follows:

**MyClass.i**

```
%module cpp

%{
    #include "MyClass.h"

%}
%typemap(csbase) somens::MyClass::BigNumbers "uint"
%include "MyClass.h"
```